# How to rediect to another page using header?

Tags: php, mysql, header

Below is a code which counts if the row effected equals 1 it should redirect to a page displaying that specific item. But I am not redirected to items.php I am sure row effected equals one I have checked my database multiple times. May be my header is wrong.

```
if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    header('Location:items.php?itemid='.$itemid.'');
}else {
     print_r($db->errorInfo());
}
```

However this link opens items.php well so probably my header is wrong. How to write it correctly?

```
<a href="items.php?itemid=<?php echo $row['itemid'] ?>"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></a>
```

Comment: The header is fine. Instead, you've already written data to the header and so you can't redirect at that point. Check before this code runs, white space, echo statements, prints...etc. All of these and more will stop you.

Comment: Redirecting using headers is something you would do on the client side with JavaScript. On the server, the general approach is to return a redirecting http status code with the new target url, like 302.

Comment: Add an `exit` function after the `header`. Change your header line to this, and try.
`header('Location: items.php?itemid='.$itemid.''); exit;`

Comment: Put space after : and add exit after headers as @JazyK said